# jQuery buggy setTimeout animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing a bug with animated elements.
When you `right-click` on a group its name-field expands
downwards so that it is revealed along with 2 other groups on the line.
And then  a animation puts it on the default state triggered
with `setTimeout()` after a few seconds.
However if you start clicking randomly and intensively on groups on the line
without waiting the current animation to finish it breaks becomes buggy and executes much faster then the given timings!

Here's the key part of the code:

```
var t = window.setTimeout(function() {
   for (var i = highFrontier; i > lowFrontier - 1; i--) {
      jQuery(groupBoxes[i]).animate({
         height: '76px'
      }, 400, 'linear', function() {});
   }
}, 3300);
```

And here's the entire application: http://jsfiddle.net/TTGr7/20/

10x for your kind help, BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the object that's being animated and remove it once the animation is done. Then if the user clicks the object while it has the class (and is busy with the animation) the system would simply ignore his request.

Comment: 10x Jeffrey that should work my mind was really in search for more complex solution

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have mutliple events piling up. I don't see it in your code, but do you have click events on elements in the area you're dealing with?

One hapbit I've gotten into is to add .stop() to event registration to ensure a previous event/animation is stopped before another is started. For example,

```
.stop().animate(....)
```